# Python conditional based on Gitbash or command prompt use

Tags: python, terminal, conditional-statements, special-characters

Is there a way to determine the terminal being used? eg. Command Prompt, GitBash, Terminal

Gitbash does not recognize certain characters such as: '█' and I want to have a conditional statement to handle this.

Something similar to OS handling eg:

```
if GitBash:
     print('*')
elif Commandprompt:
     print('█')
else:
     print('=')
```

- I didn't see an answer in the python.org docs as far as I can tell.